# Django React Python Post Request Image Classification

Tags: python, django, reactjs

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    plants_serializer = PlantSerializer(data=request.data)
    data = request.FILES['plantImage']
    path = os.path.abspath('../PlantPharmacy/media/images/ ')
    path = path.strip()
    filename = path + str(data)

    if plants_serializer.is_valid():
        plants_serializer.save()
        result = predict(filename)
        obj = Plants.objects.get(plantImage = filename)
        obj.classification = result
        obj.save()
        return Response(plants_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        print('error', plants_serializer.errors)
        return Response(plants_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hi!

So I'm trying to edit a Django database model entry (setting its "classification" field as result gotten through a prediction function), but when I search for the image (Plants.objects.get(plantImage = filename) it says file does not exist, even though I have saved it. I have a feeling that its because it takes a moment for the database to recognize the file. I am trying to find a way to work around this because I need to return the image classification, but I am unsure to do so or a way to work around it.

get a "DoesNotExist( "%s matching query does not exist."" error.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
obj = plants_serializer.save(commit=False)
obj.classification = predict(filename)
obj.save()
```

Comment: Thank you! However, i get this error: 

    "'commit' is not a valid keyword argument to the 'save()' method. "
AssertionError: 'commit' is not a valid keyword argument to the 'save()' method. If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead. You can also pass additional keyword arguments to 'save()' if you need to set extra attributes on the saved model instance. For example: 'serializer.save(owner=request.user)'.'
[29/Nov/2019 18:11:26] "POST /api/plants/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16843

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
            plants_serializer.save()
            result = predict(filename)
            plants_serializer.save(user=request.user, classification=result)
            return Response(plants_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

but got a "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:" error. I need to plants_serializer.save() before processing it, but then want to add the classification to the field in the existing entry in the DB.

Can this be done with one POST request/do i need to somehow GET the entry again before doing this? I'm not super familiar with backend.